# Upgrading QnAMaker Azure Search service

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-qna-maker

I was using the free version of the QnAMaker service which was linked to a free version of the Azure Search service. This prevented me from creating new KBs in the QnAMaker saying that I need to upgrade the Search service. Since upgrading of Search service currently not supported, as stated here- https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/12931110-allow-to-upgrade-the-pricing-tier, I created a new Search service and added updated the settings for that in my QnAMaker service. Now, when I try creating the KB and publish them, I get message that my QnAMaker's Search service is not running. I have tried restarting my QnAMaker service but that still did not work. Also, I can't delete the existing KBs from QnAMaker as it gives the same error.

I have also upgraded the QnAMaker service and the Cognitive service. Is it because the indexes are not present in the newly created Search service? I thought running the QnAMaker service should rebuild the Search indexes, not sure. Any help with this please? Let me know if I can provide more details.

Comment: Could you please provide the name of your search service that you say is not running? Could you also provide which region you've created this in?

Comment: @Arvind-MSFT Newly created search service- https://chatbotsearchservice.search.windows.net. Region- Southeast Asia. Thanks.

Comment: @Arvind-MSFT For now I have deleted the Search service and along with the QnAMaker service and it's related things. Had to recreate the QnAMaker service and the new Search service alongside. I will face this issue again when I run out of the the index/storage quota of the Search service.

Comment: Couple of points: 1. I see that the service you mentioned is basic. If you think you will run out of quota, was it not feasible to have created a Standard tier service instead? 2. Because you've deleted the service due to privacy reasons, I am unable to understand what was wrong with it, but if you have any concerns with your new service I'd recommend reaching out to azsearchdisc AT microsoft DOT com with the same details I had asked previously

Comment: @Arvind-MSFT 1. Not immediately but sometime later. Since there is no option to upgrade/downgrade as per need, I guess I have to recreate the Search. 2. Didn't delete for security reasons but it was only faster option to complete my work by recreating everything in higher tiers. Thanks for the mail ID, I will reach out in case of any issues.